# How to generate a .class.php file on the software Dia with the plugin uml2php5 with an abstract class?

Tags: php, dia

I need to generate a **.class.php** from an `UML` chart with `uml2php5` on Dia.

There is no problem with the  instanciable class which have attributes and methods, the file is correctly exported.

The issue is with the abstract class. There is no file created according to the abstract class.

You can find the generated code below :

```
<?php

require_once('User.class.php');

class Yesmeet extends User {



public final  function BecameNomeet() {

}


}
?>
```

Could you help me to generate the abstract class **User.class.php** ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the issue was that my abstract class hadn't attributes neither methods.

So umltophp can't create a class without attributes and methods.

I have the answer to my question but a general question appears to me :

In the object language, can we create an abstract class without attributes and methods ?

Thanks